# A synonym or alternative for a "chivalrous" or "gallant" man but with more negative connotation

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a slang term describing a man who always tries desperately to get the attention of ladies. This type of dude is always polite to chicks and he is highly likely to forget even his best male friend when it comes to having a flirting opportunity with a female, no matter she is a human or she belongs to another species. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Smarming = smarmy + charming.  Oh, not made up?  "Engineer" is possibly what you're looking for.

Comment: If you could specify what other species he flirts with, we might be able to narrow this down.

Comment: *Neckbeard? Fedorable? Fedorabeard?*

Comment: [medallion man:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/medallion-man) *a man who tries to look younger than he is by wearing jewellery and tight clothes, and who often has his shirt open at the front to show his chest* (presumably usually in order to attract women).

Comment: The hero of a series of video games published in the 1990s was an extremely smarmy and conquest-focused cartoon character who was prone to terrible pickup lines involving astrological signs and the like—a propensity that put a serious dent in his charm (and in his rate of success with the ladies): _Leisuresuit Larry_. Calling someone a Leisuresuit Larry may not have any resonance with young adults, but it's a funny name even if you don't know how aptly it describes this type of character.

Comment: @SvenYargs - yes, Larry, that lounge-lizard in a leisure-suit. I've actually met Larry on a number of occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a term like [womanizer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/womanizer) or [Lothario](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Lothario)? Womanizer has a very negative connotation, but is more about the frequent attention a man pays to women and doesn't necessarily imply he ignores his male friends.

Perhaps something like [skirt-chaser](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/skirt-chaser) is a bit more in your target zone?  It's fairly negative, and does seem to imply more dedication to the exclusion of other activities...

Comment: Thanks, skirt-chaser is exactly in my target zone. Other suggestions are still appreciated because I'm sure I have seen a better term somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're thinking of *white knight *. It's not quite a perfect fit but worth s shot. I'm afraid you'll have to do some reading around a variety of sources -- is not really dictionary material and there are different viewpoints signing different meanings. I'm assuming here that the polite approach is genuine. If it's an act you could consider *"nice guy"* (quite possibly with the quotes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think "white knight" is not what I'm looking for. In fact I need a term which is quite insulting. Once I came across a really great word in a novel or a movie which fit my descriptions, but now I don't recall it.

Comment: Besides, I shouldn't have used the polite part in my question, it's somehow misleading. I meant this type of dude pretends to be polite, he shows a kind of fake politeness just for the sake of impressing women.

Comment: I can't think of a single word that covers all that, tho I recognize the type. Perhaps a two-word expression such as 'chivalrous creep'?

Comment: @Damavand,that's where my 2nd suggestion comes in - he's acting nice to try to get his way but is a creep underneath. I've tried to find you a decent link but I can't find anything helpful. I'll look again on the pc rather than the phone if I get round to it tomorrow.

Comment: @Damavand try (the 2nd para of) [this opinion piece](http://jezebel.com/5838994/a-field-guide-to-nice-guys) for size.  It's one of the least depressing takes on what I'm trying to point you to.

Answer (score 0):

> **lounge lizard**
>
> A ladies-man that frequents night spots where drinks are served. May be part of the live music set, but usually the lizard is at the bar chatting up rich women. Most often seen in a suit that was a fashion statement in the 80s.

See the Urban Dictionary, “lounge lizard” [**Link**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lounge+lizard)